# Java Regex : How to search a text or a phrase in a large text

Tags: java, regex

I have a large text file and I need to search a word or a phrase in the file line by line and output the line with the text found in it.

For example, the sample text is

`And the earth was without form,
 Where [art] thou?`

if the user search for `thou` word, the only line to be display is

```
Where [art] thou?
```

and if the user search for `the earth`, the first line should be displayed.

I tried using the `contains` function but it will display also the `without` when searching only for `thou`.

This is my sample code :

```
String[] verseList = TextIO.readFile("pentateuch.txt");
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0;  i < verseList.length; i++) {
        String[] data = verseList[i].split("\t");
        String[] info3 = data[3].split(" ");
        System.out.print("Search for: ");
            String txtSearch = kbd.nextLine();
            LinkedList<String> searchedList = new LinkedList<String>();
            for (String bible : verseList){
                if (bible.contains(txtSearch)){
                    searchedList.add(bible);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if (searchedList.size() > 0){
             for (String s : searchedList){
                    String[] searchedData = s.split("\t");
                    System.out.printf("%s - %s - %s - %s \n",searchedData[0], searchedData[1], searchedData[2], searchedData[3]);
                }
            }
            System.out.print("Total: " + counter);
```

So I am thinking of using `regex` but I don't know how. 
Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Use word boundaries `\\b`.

Comment: @stribizhev, thank you for your comments, I tried that but it will not work when searching for a phrase

Comment: What doesn't work when searching for phrases?

Comment: Perhaps, it won't in some cases. Then, use `(?<!\\w)` as the front boundary and `(?!\\w)` as the end boundary.

Comment: Are your "lines" actually separated by tabs within a single "verse" String?

Comment: @stribizhev, (?<!\\w) did the magic, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sometimes variables have non-word characters at boundary positions, you cannot rely on `\b` word boundary.

In such cases, it is safer to use look-arounds `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)`, i.e. in Java, something like:

`"(?<!\\w)" + searchedData[n] + "(?!\\w)"`

Answer (score 1):

To match a String that contains a *word*, use this code:

```
String txtSearch; // eg "thou"

if (str.matches(".*?\\b" + txtSearch + "\\b.*"))
   // it matches
```

This code builds a regex that only matches if both ends of `txtSearch` fall and the start/end of a word in the string by using `\b`, which means "word boundary".

Comment: Will the wildcard matching cause a lot of backtracking?

Comment: @James a bit, but the input is tiny. Anyway, I have adopted your implied suggestion :)